# Amazon SES not working with eu_west_1 but ok using us_east_1 PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Im rewriting a few scripts to make use of the new v4 signature for Amazon AWS.

I am trying to send an email using the code on this page:

https://github.com/okamos/php-ses

When I use his code exactly as it is just adding secret keys etc I get an error saying my email address isnt verified on us_east_1. This makes sense as all my things are on EU_WEST_1.

So Ive tried adding the EU endpoint as a third parameter but get this error:

*'Warning: SimpleEmailService::sendEmail(): 6 Could not resolve host: EU_WEST_1'*

This is the line of code which seems to work but connecting to the wrong endpoint

```
$ses = new SimpleEmailService('apikey', 'secretkey');
print_r($ses->sendEmail($m));
```

I have tried adding the new endpoint as the third parameter like this

```
$ses = new SimpleEmailService('apikey', 'secret','eu-west-1');
```

But that just generates the error.

Can anyone tell me the correct code to use to set the eu-west-1 endpoint to send emails through?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the regions have dashes, not underlines?

Comment: Ive tried with every combination of dashes and underscores but same result

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem with AWS PHP library for uploading files to S3. Even though I was setting up the region from us-east-1 to eu-west-1 it was still taking us-east-1 as by default. I would suggest you to look for region configurations in library and how it is overriding.

SES Email Host for us-east-1 and eu-west-1 are different. So even though if you are passing correct API and Secret, it might not work because of default region.

If this debug process doesn't work can share the screenshot of what you region you are getting before email dispatch. I would love to explore further.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

Looks like there was a typo within the code on github, it had these 3 lines in the file 'SimpleEmailServices.php:

```
    const AWS_US_EAST_1 = 'email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
    const AWS_US_WEST_2 = 'email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com';
    const AWS_EU_WEST1 = 'email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com';
```

He'd missed the underscore in the AWS_EU_WEST1.